# Problem downloading a game

Tags: discussion

Well, I'm having trouble donwloading a game on my phone (Android). I know that if this is on topic the answers here will save me.

The problem is that when I try to download the game (Clash of Clans) from Google Play, the download starts, but when it is done something like the next message:

> Cant install "Clash of Clans" in the default location...

So, is that on topic?

Comment: Depends on if you add enough information for us to be able to help diagnose your issue.

Comment: It may be on topic here. But it's more likely to be on topic (and to get a good answer) at http://android.stackexchange.com since it sounds like it's more of a Play Store -problem than a game problem.

Comment: thanks, will try it there

Comment: Also it sounds like youve simply run out of room. Thats the only time Ive seen that sort of error message

Comment: Thanks for checking first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While we *may* leave your question open and try to help you, your question may not get much attention or answers, even if you include lots of information. **This is because our site is more skilled in games rather than technical support for games.**

However, the **[Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/)** site is probably the better site for you. From their [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Ask about...
>
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue with Android

They also have tags for [the Google Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store) (~1.5k questions) and [downloading](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downloading) (~200 questions), so they are probably better equipped than us to answer your question.